# Video Progress not updating on click - Javascript

Tags: javascript, video-player

Hey Guys i am trying to make my new Video player and while i am moving video progress bar, it was not work. when i am double click it actually working.

HTML:

```
<video
      src="gone.mp4"
      id="video"
      class="screen"
      poster="poster.png"
    ></video>
    <div class="controls">
      <button class="btn" id="play">
        <i class="fa fa-play fa-2x"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="btn" id="stop">
        <i class="fa fa-stop fa-2x"></i>
      </button>
      <input
        type="range"
        id="progress"
        class="progress"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        step="0.1"
        value="0"
      />
      <span class="timestamp" id="timestamp">00:00</span>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
const video = document.getElementById("video"),
      play = document.getElementById("play"),
      stop = document.getElementById("stop"),
      progress = document.getElementById("progress"),
      timestamp = document.getElementById("timestamp");



video.addEventListener("click", toggleVideoStatus);
video.addEventListener("pause", updatePlayIcon);
video.addEventListener("play", updatePlayIcon);
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateProgress);

play.addEventListener("click", toggleVideoStatus);
stop.addEventListener("click", stopVideo)

progress.addEventListener("change", setVideoProgress);


function toggleVideoStatus(){
    if(video.paused){
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();
    }
}

function updatePlayIcon() {
    if(video.paused){
        play.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-play fa-2x'></i>";
    } else {
        play.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-pause fa-2x'></i>";
    }
}

function updateProgress() {
  // console.log(video.currentTime); // Streaming Current Seconds
  // console.log(video.duration); // Total Video Time
  progress.value = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;

  // Get Minutes

  let mins = Math.floor(video.currentTime / 60 );
  if(mins < 10){
    mins = "0" + String(mins);
  }

  // Get Seconds

  let secs = Math.floor(video.currentTime % 60);
  if(secs < 10){
    secs = "0" + String(secs);
  }

  timestamp.innerHTML = `${mins} : ${secs}`;

}

function setVideoProgress() {
  video.currentTime = (+progress.value * video.duration) / 100
}

function stopVideo(){
  video.currentTime = 0;
  video.pause();
}
```

For Progress Bar I used Change event... for single click video buffer i used click event and this one also i am seeing any good result.
please let me know if anything i am missing..

Comment: Typo, instead of `puase` use `pause`? As `video.addEventListener("pause", updatePlayIcon);`

Comment: @skobaljic, Thanks for reply the time u put comment i am still editing post.. sorry for that.. my actual problem was on progress bar click video foreword and backward not working if i am double click on video progress it was working... this i am facing issue